# openid: login without redirect

Tags: php, flash, openid

I'm new to opeid, so forgive if the question is dump. I'm developing a system (on PHP) to unify login through various openid-providers. There should be several methods (login, check if user is logined and etc).

The problems is that the system will be used by flash. And I don't know how to perform login without redirect. Here's my question: if a user is already logined on open-id provider (or uses provider like myopenid which don't need password) and has confirmed that he allows to use his personal info, is it possible to login without redirect (to login page on openid provider). An example will be great!

Will be grateful for any thoughts!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform an [immediate request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor28) to the provider, i.e. by setting the parameter `openid.mode` to `checkid_immediate`. The provider MUST respond with a respons whether the authentication was succesfull or not. If the authentication was not succesfull, you should still perform the redirect to allow the user to authenticate.